# iAd implementation inside swipe recognizer

Tags: objective-c

My app is basically build up with UISwipeGestureRecognizer - changes text on screen and background color when a swipe to either side is made. Right now I can make iAd run on startup of the app, and hide itself when it's not loading. However I would like to have the code for this run with every swipe - as otherwise I believe any number of swipes would still count as one view(?)

I have been using this code, which runs with an AD Bannerview that I've dragged into my storyboard:

```
#pragma mark iAd Delegate Methods

-(void) bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner {
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
[banner setAlpha:1];
[UIView commitAnimations];

}


 -(void) bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error {

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
[banner setAlpha:0];
[UIView commitAnimations];

 }
```

Comment: please, dear developers, use the damn block-based animation instead, that is Apple's recommendation since iOS4... it was about 4 years ago by now.

Comment: I have personally spent a lot of time on this, probably because I'm still new to objective c. Do you have any link(s) in particular that you'd recommend?

Comment: I knew it was not part of the original question, but normally the `UIView` Class Reference holds those information for developers: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html, especially the section _Animation_ and section _Animating Views with Block Objects_.

Comment: As far as I can see this page https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/Conceptual/iAd_Guide/WorkingwithBannerViews/WorkingwithBannerViews.html
explains most of what should be necessary to implement, but I still wouldn't know how to use this inside my swipe functions. Maybe I could set the swipe functions to call the other function, but then I would need the part where it checks if an ad has loaded or not